# Casting dynamic to generic

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<DynamicAttributeValue<T>> Read<T>(EntityType entityType, long entityId, string shortName, OptionSearch optionSearch = OptionSearch.Name)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(object))
    {
        return Read(entityType, entityId, shortName, optionSearch);
    }

    return ReadWithOptions<T>(entityType, entityId, shortName, optionSearch).Values;
}

public static IEnumerable<DynamicAttributeValue<dynamic>> Read(EntityType entityType, long entityId, string shortName, OptionSearch optionSearch = OptionSearch.Name)
{
    var datatype = GetDefinition(shortName, entityType).DataType;
    switch (datatype)
    {
        case DataType.MultipleChoice:
            throw new NotSupportedException("Multiple choice attributes are not supported.");
        case DataType.Integer:
            return (dynamic)ReadWithOptions<int>(entityType, entityId, shortName, optionSearch).Values;
        case DataType.Text:
            return (dynamic)ReadWithOptions<string>(entityType, entityId, shortName, optionSearch).Values;
        case DataType.Bit:
            return (dynamic)ReadWithOptions<bool>(entityType, entityId, shortName, optionSearch).Values;
        case DataType.Decimal:
            return (dynamic)ReadWithOptions<decimal>(entityType, entityId, shortName, optionSearch).Values;
        case DataType.BigInt:
            return (dynamic)ReadWithOptions<long>(entityType, entityId, shortName, optionSearch).Values;
        case DataType.Float:
            return (dynamic)ReadWithOptions<float>(entityType, entityId, shortName, optionSearch).Values;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

Where I am trying to use `Read()` to give a specific underlying type if they supply an object or dynamic in T.

However I am getting the following error:

> cannot implicitly convert type
>   `system.collections.generic.ienumerable<DynamicAttributeValue<dynamic>>`
>   to  `system.collections.generic.ienumerable<DynamicAttributeValue<T>>`.
>   An explicity conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I am lost at how to cast a return that is essentially

`IEnumerable<DynamicAttributeValue<int>>` to `IEnumerable<DynamicAttributeValue<object>>` or `IEnumerable<DynamicAttributeValue<dynamic>>` when I know that T is an object or dynamic.

I am OK about throwing a runtime error if they try to give it a custom object for some reason  such as  `Read<CustomObject>`  that obviously should throw a runtime error. I am only supporting `Read<dynamic>` or `Read<object>`

Comment: Please include the complete text of the error *as text* in the question, showing where you're receiving it - ideally as part of a [mcve]. There's no benefit in a screenshot there.

Comment: If all you support is two types why use generics. Just make two methods with diffrent names, `ReadObject(` and `ReadDynamic(`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: `ReadWithOptions` seems to support a lot of different types (judging by the way it is called) so I'm not sure where you are getting that it only supports two types...

Comment: Sorry, I support all native types (int, double, float, bool, etc) and then also object and dynamic.  When they supply an object or dynamic I want it to figure out the best underlying datatype to use.

Comment: I don't think you really want an overload for `dynamic`.  Using `object` means "an object of any underlying type."  Using `dynamic` means "an object of unknown type and please don't do any type checking either because trust me I know what it's supposed to be."  If you're already doing type checking to determine what the underlying type is, `dynamic` doesn't buy you anything.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to implicitly go from dynamic to T without helping the compiler out a little more.  If you know that Type T is going to be of a certain class then you can try using a type constraint to see if the compiler likes that better:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters.